# Composition over Inheritance Real life example

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

I am trying to understand the phrase "favor composite over inheritance".

Could someone give me a real life example why composition is better than inheritance.

Also if there are any drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is when a class is a type of another and shares the base functionality and properties of other classes of the same type.

e.g `Vehicle -> Car`.
Vehicle might have properties (composition) like `weight` or `topSpeed` that all classes inherited from it will share.

Composition is the specific makeup of the properties of a class, e.g. `Car -> int numDoors`. Methods also represent composition, but often with overridden child class implementations in the case of inheritance. For example, the `drive` method of `Vehicle` might have common implementation related to gas consumption, while `Car` could override that method by perhaps first calling the base method of `Vehicle` (`super.drive()`), and then further specifying its own specific process.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance.